# Rigify: If FK is Working, IK Stops working (and vice-versa)

Tags: rigging, armature, rigify, inverse-kinematics

I added a Meta-Human Armature to these arms, and as their normal bones everything works fine. When I Generate a Rigify Rig off the armature, there's this setting "IK-FK (hand.L)" (or hand.R) where if it is 0, the red (FK) works fine.
[image: IK-FK hand.L: 0, FK works, IK does not]
But if I change this value to 1, all greens (FK) work now, but the reds (FK) do not. Those parts of the rig move, but the mesh does not move with them.
[image: IK-FK hand.L: 1, FK does not work, IK does]
I can set this value to 0.5, and then both half-work. The rig moves, but the mesh only moves half the distance it should.
[image: IK-FK hand.L: 0.5, FK and IK work partially]

Is there a way to make both of these parts of the rig work at the same time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal. Only one control type can be active.

There is IK > FK and FK > IK Snap buttons under Rig Main Properties. They can match the position of the IK controls to the FK one or vice-versa.

Also, there is a button called "Action" next to each of the snap buttons. It can convert an IK animation/action to an FK one and vice-versa.